# Mongoose querying wrong collection with $text search

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am attempting to query a *compound* **text** index set on two of my fields utilizing the MongoDB *$text search*.

creating the indexes have been no problem and calling `db.card.getIndexes()` in the **mongo shell** returns the following:

```
{
                "v" : 2,
                "key" : {
                        "_id" : 1
                },
                "name" : "_id_",
                "ns" : "adatabase.cards"
        },
        {
                "v" : 2,
                "key" : {
                        "_fts" : "text",
                        "_ftsx" : 1
                },
                "name" : "name_text_description_text",
                "ns" : "adatabase.cards",
                "weights" : {
                        "description" : 3,
                        "name" : 5
                },
                "background" : true,
                "default_language" : "english",
                "language_override" : "language",
                "textIndexVersion" : 3
        }
```

Upon querying the **cards** collection through the following express route:

```
router.route('/searchcards')
  .post((req, res, next) => {
    let query = req.query.q;
    Card.find({
      $text: { $search: query }
    }, { score: { $meta: "textScore" } }
    ).sort( { score: { $meta: "textScore" } } )
    .then(q => {
      console.log(q); 
      res.send(q)
    })
    .catch(next)
  });
```

I receive the error:

```
MongoError: text index required for $text query (no such collection 'adatabase.users')
```

Why would mongo attempt to query a users collection?

Here is my Mongoose Card Schema.

```
const CardSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {type: String, required: true, maxlength: [100, 'Name must be less than 100 characters']},
  user: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
  days: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Day'}],
  locations: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Location'}],
  description: {type: String, required: true, maxlength: [500, 'Description must be less than 500 characters']},
  settings: {
      private: {type: Boolean, required: true, default: false}
  },
  meta: {
      created: { type : Date, default: Date.now },
      view_count: {type: Number, default: 0},
      tags: [String],
      likes: {type: Number, default: 0},
      numberOfComments: {type: Number, default: 0},
      numberOfShares: {type: Number, default: 0}
  },
    comments: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment'}],
});

CardSchema.options.autoIndex = true;

CardSchema.index({
  name: 'text',
  description: 'text',
}, {
  weights: {
    name: 5,
    description: 3,
  },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was importing the Card Model from the users model path. WOW!